# JS: Promise doesn't return value

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, gm

I need to get a value of an asynchronous function. I tried to use Promise, but that does not work:

```
const res = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  gm(readStream).size({ bufferStream: true }, function (err, size) {
    if (!err) resolve(size)
  })
})
console.log(res)
```

The result I get is `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: Using promises doesn't make your code synchronous.  `res.then(function (ret) { console.log(ret); })`

Comment: Don't need to be sarcastic here @adeneo. You were a beginner once.

Comment: Well, you've asked question before where you've actually used promises, and async/await, and callbacks, so you clearly know what asynchronous is, unless you're just copy/pasting random questions for the fun?

Comment: I mean -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948918/nodejs-restify-how-can-i-recieve-file-upload-in-api come on !

Comment: Obviously I've some problems understanding those things. I think for me there are some misunderstandings. That's why I'asking this basic question. Still I'm not able to convert the answer of nadavvadan to a async/await version

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Promises are an abstraction for callbacks, not magic. They can't make asynchronous code synchronous.

The correct solution is:

```
const res = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  gm(readStream).size({ bufferStream: true }, function (err, size) {
    if (err) reject(err);
    else resolve(size);

  })
});

res.then(function(promiseResolutionValue) {
    console.log(res)
})
```

You could also use `async / await` here:

```
const getSize = readStream => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    gm(readStream).size({ bufferStream: true }, function (err, size) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(size);
    })
  });
}


let printSize = async readStream => {
  console.log(`Size is ${await getSize(readStream)}`);
}
```

Or, if you're using NodeJS (Version 8+), you might be able to adapt your function to use `util.promisify`.
Other `Promise` libraries, such as `Bluebird`, also offer such functions, to easily convert 'standard' node-style functions (functions that have a callback with `err, data` as arguments) into promise-returning equivalents.

Or just use the callback.

Comment: I think you could have been nicer, but this is the correct answer!

Comment: You could also add `async` / `await` to the example, which kind of is magic and does sort of _make asynchronous code synchronous._

Comment: I did not mean to be rude at all, sorry if it came out that way.

Comment: I do believe async/await is the way to go; Will edit and add an example later.

Comment: Would be great if you could add an async/await example

Comment: @user3142695 - added

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be looked like this:

```
const res = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  gm(readStream).size({ bufferStream: true }, function (err, size) {
    if (!err) resolve(size)
    else reject(err)
  })
})

function onResolved(data) {
  console.log('data: ', data);
}

function onRejected(err) {
  console.log('err:', err);
}

res.then(onResolved, onRejected);
```

Promise does not make your code synchronous, it lets you control when you want to get the result, not immediately like `callback` style.